# Inserting Input Field value from variable returns empty record in Database

Tags: asp-classic

i have an input field whose value is coming from a variable, when i submit the form record insert as an empty row :(

if i check the view-source of my page it clearly prints the value but does not insert it.

Here is the Input Field:

```
<input name="uid" type="text" value="<%Response.Write(studentid)%>" disabled="disabled" />
```

Here is the Insert Code:

```
<%

if request.Form("MyRecord")="Insert" then
Set InsCom=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
InsCom.ActiveConnection=objConn
InsF = Trim(request.Form("uid"))
InsF = replace(InsF,"'","''")
InsCom.CommandText = "Insert into talent_hunt(uid)Values(?) "
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@uid", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsF)
InsCom.Execute
response.Write"Record Inserted Successfully!<br /><a href=""talent-hunt.asp"" />Go Back to main page</a>"
end if

%>
```

Please help...

Comment: use `readOnly` instead of `disabled` in your form field http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524222/how-can-i-get-the-form-value-from-a-disabled-input-element

Comment: @SearchAndResQ why not post this as answer? :)

Comment: it's already answered in that thread. but i will add, just to close :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `readOnly` instead of `disabled`.

ref. thread: [How can I get the form value from a disabled <input> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524222/how-can-i-get-the-form-value-from-a-disabled-input-element)