# How to get values from disabled inputs in webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My html code is -

```
    <input id="txtPortalLogin" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" disabled="disabled" placeholder="No Link" value=""/>
```

Please assist some code to get the values from disabled field. 
Screenshot is attached so that you will find the which text values i am talking about. 
[Input Fields are disabled and I want values from shown screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5ORA.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429070/selenium-wd-get-value-of-disabled-input go to this link and u will get details.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to get this value with Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('your_page_url')
disabled_input_field = driver.find_element_by_id("txtPortalLogin")
value = disabled_input_field.get_attribute('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript executor in selenium to execute a javascript code which return the value of the  html element ( input). Something simmilar to the below

```
 String value = "";
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    String value = (String)((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
        .executeScript("return document.getElementById('txtPortalLogin').value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# it would be

`driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtPortalLogin")).GetAttribute("value");`

however you could also do this using the JavaScript executor as so:

`var value = ((IJavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return $('#txtPortalLogin').attr('value')").ToString();`

EDIT; I think the OP might want to get the `https://production` etc part out of the field. I'm not 100% sure how to do that, sorry.

I did also find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524222/how-can-i-get-the-form-value-from-a-disabled-input-element) which might be able to answer your problem; TLDR is make it readonly instead of disabled which allows the value behind to still be accessible but not changeable by the user.

Comment: There is a shorter way $('#txtPortalLogin').val(); however that is jQuery not a clear javascript

Comment: OP didn't specify that it had to be pure JavaScript. This is pure speculation and probably an error on my part as I am not a JavaScript dev, but is JQuery not fairly common if not a staple of most sites?

Answer (score 0):

Usually `driver.getAtribute("value");` works. But as value field is empty, you'll have to go for JavaScriptExecutor -

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;

String value = je.executeScript("return angular.element(arguments[0]).scope().{{modalValue:put modal value from HTML}};", {{webElement}}).toString();

return value;
```