# ASP.NET Core view model when disabling form fields with jQuery.validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, jquery-validate

I have an HTML form, and I would like it so that when the user clicks the submit button, the button and all input elements (textboxes mainly) in the form are disabled, to prevent them from changing any data, or clicking the button a second time. I'm using `jQuery.validate` on the form without the unobtrusive plug-in.

The markup for the form looks like this (irrelevant markup removed for clarity)...

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Jim">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="Name">Your name</label>
    <input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="Email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have the following JavaScript that uses `jQuery.validate`...

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: {
    UserName: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3
    },
    Email: {
      required: true
    },
    Message: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

That's all the JavaScript on the page.

This works fine. However, if I add one line into the submitHandler function...

```
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("form input").prop('disabled', true);
    form.submit();
  }
```

...then when the form is submitted, `Request.Form` is empty, so none of my data is sent to the server.

It seems to be related to `jQuery.validate`, as if I completely replace the JavaScript with this...

```
$(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(form) {
    $("form input").prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

...then the controls are disabled and my data comes through fine. This seem to imply I'm doing something wrong with `jQuery.validate`.

Anyone able to explain why my data doesn't come through when I disable the controls when using `jQuery.validate`?

Comment: ASP?  Are you using the Unobtrusive Validation plugin or not?

Comment: @Sparky No I'm not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that disabled inputs are not submitted with the form.Refer to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#disabled) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524222/how-can-i-get-the-form-value-from-a-disabled-input-element).

You should use the `readonly` attribute rather than `disabled`. Read-only fields cannot be edited by the user, but are still submitted with the form.

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    $("form input").prop('readonly', true);
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: That's great, exactly what I wanted. makes more sense to use `readonly` I guess, although I'm still puzzled why the data was posted when I didn't use `jQuery.validate`